# is there a way for new rows to appear in excel based on a data validation answer?

Tags: excel

i am creating a matrix survey in excel and i want to know if there is a way for, depending on the chosen data validation answer, new rows to appear.
one question on the survey is a yes or no question and i have create a data validation choice. in the event that 'yes' is chosen, i would like 3 new rows to appear for more fields to be filled in. some people were telling me that i need to create a macro for this, but being very new to excel, i was hoping there was a different option.

please let me know if/how this is possible

thanks

Comment: You could already have those rows filled, but use an `if()` formula to display the survey question if they choose yes or no in your validation cell. In the cell that will hold the question (assuming the data validation yes/no cell is A1:  `IF(A1="Yes", "My question that needs to be answered", "")`

Comment: if you need to insert rows with the questions, then you definately need VBA